# Why the number of partitions 8 has with at most 3 positive parts is equal to when it has exactly 3 nonnegative parts?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

In a textbook there is a question about partitions that follows:

Find the number of partitions of 8 that have

(c) at most three positive parts;

(d) exactly three nonnegative parts.

For c) I simply got $P(8,1)$ + $P(8,2)$ + $P(8,3)$ = $10$

and for d) I got the same answer by doing P(8,3) plus all of the partitions that can have $0$s in them ${ (008), (017), (026), (035), (044) }$ So $5 + 5 = 10$

The next question in the book asks to find $P(11,3)$ which equals $10$ as well and then asks to explain why parts c), d) and $P(11.3)$ are equal. I am having a difficult time understanding how all these relate to each other. I am trying to create a practical example in my head but no luck. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For c and d, you have essentially described the natural bijection: pad with $0$ if necessary.

For a bijection between d and $P(11,3)$: given a partition of $8$ into  exactly three nonnegative parts, add $1$ to each part; given a partition of $11$ into exactly $3$ parts, subtract $1$ from each part.

Comment: Ah, I see. Writing them all out made it clear how it all connected. Thank you!